# Project folder not visible in Sublime Text 2 after relaunching app

Tags: macos, sublimetext

When I add a new project folder to Sublime Text 2…

[image: Screenshot]

It works normally. But when I quit and relaunch the application I can't see my project folder on the sidebar?

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried saving the project? (Save Project As...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding folders to projects or otherwise changing projects will be retained for as long as the instance of the app is open. Your changes will be lost when the app is quit unless you **save the project**.